# In xdebug Step Over, Step Into and Step Out buttons are disabled

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, debugging, xdebug

We are using Visual Studio Code and trying to debug. When we try to debug, the "Step Over", "Step Into" and "Step Out" buttons are seems disabled as in this image:

[image]

We installed WAMP 3.3.2. Then enabled Xdebug. We followed Xdebug installation wizard and till this everything works as expected.

Then we opened Visual Studio Code and installed PHP debug (V1.34.0). Then included `runtimeExecutable` in `launch.json`.

Then we clicked "Run and Debug -> Start Debugging". We could see 'Running' in Call stack. But the "Step Over", "Step Into" and "Step Out" buttons are disabled and not able to display variables and see their values in each step.

php.ini setting is as below

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp332/bin/php/php8.2.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll"
;xdebug.mode allowed are : off develop coverage debug gcstats profile trace
xdebug.mode =develop
xdebug.output_dir ="c:/wamp332/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.log="c:/wamp332/logs/xdebug.log"
;xdebug.log_level : 0 Criticals, 1 Connection, 3 Warnings, 5 Communication, 7 Information, 10 Debug Breakpoint
xdebug.log_level=7
xdebug.profiler_output_name=trace.%H.%t.%p.cgrind
xdebug.use_compression=false
```

But I no errors are logged in xdebug.log. Please suggest

Comment: *`xdebug.mode =develop`* -- I believe you need to also have `debug` there, e.g. `xdebug.mode=debug,develop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @LazyOne, for debugging you need to include `debug` in the `xdebug.mode` setting, such as in:

```
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
```